# Javascript Option Part Italic

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I would like to make the first word of my HTML Option Italic but only the text in the dropdown menu changes, the selected item remains in normal font.

```
 <select name="selectGene" id="selectGene">
<option value="gene"> Homo sapiens BCL3 </option> 
</select>    
<script>
    var opt = document.getElementById("selectGene").options[0];
    var str = "Homo sapiens"
    opt.innerHTML = str.italics() + " BCL3";
</script>
```

Comment: `option` elements can contain text content only, you can not place additional HTML elements into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot partially style the option, the styles are native to the platform used.

The below link is jquery plugin which is using div and list elements to simulate select options and you will be able to apply your styles.

https://plugins.jquery.com/selectric/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work for you.

```
<select name="selectGene" id="selectGene">
<option value="gene"> Homo sapiens BCL3 </option> 
<option value="gene"> Homo sapiens BCL31 </option> 
<option value="gene"> Homo sapiens BCL32 </option> 
<option value="gene"> Homo sapiens BCL33 </option> 
</select> 

<script>
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementById("selectGene").options.length;i++){ 
    var opt = document.getElementById("selectGene").options[i];
    opt.style.fontStyle= "italic";
}
</script>
```